# Why does not Modal dialog work with latest version of Jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am a naive user of jquery 1.4.2. For showing cool modal dialog box on my webpage I am using it. It flickers when I open the modal dialog and then it disappears :)

```
$("#AlertBox").dialog({resizable: false,modal: true,autoOpen: false, show: 'slide', position: 'center',width:405});
$("#AlertBox").css({ visibility: "visible", cursor: "pointer" });
$("#AlertBox").dialog("open");
```

Comment: It would be helpful to see some code.

Comment: Pls check out re-edited question !

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that you are using ***jquery-ui-1.8.custom.min.js*** with ***jquery-1.4.2.min.js***. I have faced same problem today I refered following link --> http://forum.jquery.com/topic/common-problem-jquery-ui-and-jquery-1-4-x

Answer (score 0):

Have you included properly all the required .js files and the .css files in the webpage?
Which modal dialog box are you using?

Perhaps you have included an external javascript or css file which is not loading properly?